# Using Android speech API in Windows

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to experiment with Monodroid in C#. I'm aware that Android applications can be run on Windows using the emulator. Is it possible to use the Android API in a Windows console application? I would like to use the Android speech recognizer without actually running it in an emulator on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No-- Android API is (partly) based on firmware designed to run on a particular hardware platform--

The emulator emulates the platform at the hardware level, which is why the API runs in the emulator.

The API won't run without the emulator.

The speech recognizer in Android uses a Google web service to do most of the work, anyway.  The phone just captures the audio-- the recognition happens on Google servers.